# What was the galaxy formation Rust saw before confronting Erol Childress?

Tags: true-detective

What was the galaxy formation Rust saw before confronting Erol Childress in [*True Detective*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt2356777/) S01E08?

It was weird like out of the series.
I guess it was some sort of hallucination, a product of Rust's madness or addiction.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

**TL;DR**

Yes, it's a (symbolic) hallucination.

**Long answer**

Throughout the investigation in the first season of *True Detective*, Det. Rust Cohle keeps coming across the symbols of a spiral and black stars that are linked to the crimes perpetrated in 'Carcosa':

[image] [image]

We also discover that Cohle is frequently hallucinating as a result of his drug abuse during his long stint as an undercover cop, and at a certain point in this investigation, he imagines a flock of birds forming the above spiral:

[image]

It seems fitting, then, that he hallucinates a cosmic vortex upon finally finding 'Carcosa'. This is symbolic, according to *True Detective* director Cary Fukunaga:

> We landed on the spiral formation of the clouds as a wrapping-up of the symbology, or at least a book-ending of the symbology. I liked the idea that we could actually see Carcosa and black stars. If you look really closely, you can see black orbs floating in it.

[image]

Of course, we can always assume that this is mystical or that Cohle has ESP. But *True Detective* creator Nic Pizzolatto suggests otherwise [in this interview](http://www.ew.com/ew/article/0,,20791143,00.html):

> I hope the audience will be pleasantly surprised by the naturalism of the entire story. If you look at the series so far, what seems supernatural actually has real-world causes, like Cohle's hallucinations or even the nature of the crime. It has occult portents, but **there is nothing supernatural about it.**

Comment: I confuses me, to see a galaxy, doesn't have any supernatural? this doesn't makes sense (to me at least). Great answer though.